In UK civil practice, what is the correct term for for an ultimate judgement after multiple hearings?
I have, for an extended period, been the claimant in a UK (England & Wales) Employment Tribunal action. We have progressed past a five-day Hearing plus a one-day Remedy Hearing, the judge indicated that an in-person hearing for some final matters would probably not be necessary and neither party has objected to that.
The timeframe for reconsideration or appeal has now expired. No Case Management Orders are outstanding. Neither party has applied for a written judgement.
I am aware that terms such as "summary judgement" and "final judgement" have special meaning in a legal context, as obviously does "written judgement" as distinct from a letter advising the parties of the judge's decision.
What is the appropriate term for a "wrapping up" letter (or email etc.) that finally summarises the judge's decision on amounts owed etc.?

ET 'judgments' (and the documents containing them) are called 'decisions', and if financial awards are made in a separate document issued after the main decision, this will be done in an 'award decision'. If you are a party and you want to prod the judge, call or write to the ET office handling the case, having the case ref no handy. Note spelling - UK court decisions are called judgments.

Thanks @MichaelHarvey, the decisions have been made but details regarding restitution have to be finalised since the judge has found that the law contradicts itself. Correspondence has been continuing sporadically for years...

The Employment Appeal Tribunal, in a series of four conjoined appeals (the lead case being Kwamin v Abbey National plc), has handed down guidance on what delays are, and are not, acceptable between a case finishing and the tribunal issuing its decision. If there is excessive delay then this, without more, will give rise to grounds for appeal. https://www.danielbarnett.co.uk/site/blog/employment-blog/delay-by-employment-tribunals-2004.html
